# How to scrape all full-text reviews tripadvisor

Tags: r, web-scraping, review, tripadvisor

I can't scrape all the reviews for a specific hotel (I need full-text reviews).

I've tried some functions like ".nav.next" and "jump_to", but code is not working for some reasons. The code is following:

```
url <- read_html ("https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g297630-d1194844-r675391794-The_Gateway_Hotel_Old_Port_Rd_Mangalore-Mangalore_Dakshina_Kannada_District_Karn.html")

getXreviews10pages <- function(url, X){
   data <- data.frame()
   i = 1
   for(i in 1:X){
     if(i != 1){ # Go to next page but don't skip the first page
       next_URL <- html_nodes(url, ".nav.next") %>%
          html_attr("href")
       url <- jump_to(url, paste0("https://www.tripadvisor.com", next_URL))
     }
     reviewpages <- url %>%
     html_nodes(".is-9 > .prw_reviews_text_summary_hsx .partial_entry") %>%
     print(paste0("Page ", i))
    }
   data
  }

hotels_reviews <- getXreviews10pages(url, 10)
```

So I expected it to show all the reviews for the first 10 pages. ".nav.next" and jump_to are supposed to lead to the next page and then the next after and scrape all the reviews.

I'm not a coder, but I need the reviews for my Master Thesis. I couldn't find any help online. Thank you in advance for any answers!

Comment: This is because the content of the page is loaded dynamically. That is, an initial page is loaded in the web browser which contains only partial data, and javascript code that is executed by the web browser to load the additional data that you see on the page. The `read_html()` function only reads the initial page and is not capable of running the javascript code to load the rest of the page.

Comment: @RobertBaron thank you for your answer! do you have an idea of how to scrape those reviews otherwise?

Comment: You could use other technologies. I know it is feasible in C# with WinForms WebBrowser control. You can also search stack overflow with the keywords "scraping dynamic site".

Comment: You can try the RSelenium package.  Be sure to read the terms of service before attempting to scrape a commercial website or ask about it.